# The screen turns blank after passwords

Tags: password

I'm very hopeless with technology. This morning when I tried to start my laptop, everything went well until I put the password. After I put the password, the screen just went blank, but the cursor is still on the screen (and moving). I tried opening the terminal (tty1) and did google, (and did a few things: updating, removing etc) but I don't seem to understand anything =(

My version:
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64)

And I noticed this error message:

```
E: The package gir1.2-ibus-1.0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

And yes. I am hopeless and lost.